# Redux saga use action types as props

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I am new to React & Redux.

```
export function* putMatchesAsync({payload}) {
    console.log('putMatchesAsync');
    try {
        const { resMatch } = yield axios.put(baseUrl + apiEndPoint + payload.id, payload);
        yield put(putMatchesSuccess(resMatch))
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(putMatchesFailure(error.message))
    }
}
```

using this code I would like to use putMatchesSuccess or putMatchesFailure as props. Is that possible?

```
    const FixtureDetailItem = ({ type, match, teams, isAdmin, postMatchesStart, putMatchesStart, postMatchesSuccess, putMatchesSuccess }) => {
      return (
       console.log(putMatchesSuccess)
       console.log(putMatchesFail)
    )

    }

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  postMatchesStart: (matches) => dispatch(postMatchesStart(matches)),
  putMatchesStart: (matches) => dispatch(putMatchesStart(matches)),
  postMatchesSuccess: (matches) => dispatch(postMatchesSuccess(matches)),
  putMatchesSuccess: (matches) => dispatch(putMatchesSuccess(matches))
})
```

My final goal is once I get fail type then I will show alert to user, and once I get success I would like to update the state isPutSuccess.
Can anyone help?

Comment: You have a functional component? `mapDispatchToProps` is for class components, you should use the dispatch hook for functional components.

Comment: really? didn't know mapDispatchToProps is only for functional components. Let me try studying dispatch hook to see if it works.

Comment: I think you can still use mapDispatchToProps from functional components. Reference:https://dev.to/gsto/new-redux-hooks-a-before-and-after-comparison-are-they-better-loj

Comment: Yes, looks like. Thanks for that info - the point about testability may be a good one.

Comment: So, your code looks ok (as much as shown). What's the error?

Comment: @eric99 there isn't an error. I just want to do some actions depending on the fetch result. For example, once it successes, I want to use that isSuccess props to javascript function, else I want to have an alert. However, I am not sure if I can use action types as props.

Comment: It's a bit vague, and you might get closed for asking a 'give me a tutorial' type question. Why didn't you follow that page you linked?

Comment: Getting dispatch function return value would be the right question

Comment: I maybe understand (or maybe not) - you want to want to invoke `postMatchesStart` then see in you get success or fail? Redux is one-way data flow, so you you should use `mapStateToProps` to get the result, not `mapDispatchToProps` - thats for sending requests only. Your example it not at all clear.

Comment: @eric99 https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware/issues/21 this helped me how to find a result of api. Thx for help though. I learned useDispatch cause of you!